# how to correlate categorical and interval scaled data in R

Tags: r, correlation, spearman-rho

I would like to investigate the correlation of visually and automated assesed amount of emphysema (%) in CT-scans.

visual: categorical data (*visual score 1-4, score 1= 1-25%, score 2= 26-50%, score 3=51-75%, score 4= 76-100%*)

automated: interval scaled data (*1-100%*)

Since the data is not parametric, I thought about to use a spearman correlation test.

Is this correct? Is there any other test that would fit better?

Comment: What do you mean with “the data is not parametric”?

Comment: Visual appears to be an ordinal variable.  It's probably not best to use it as a categorical variable.

Comment: The data is not normally distributed. And yes, visual is an ordinal variable.

Comment: You might look into polyserial correlation.  "[polyserial correlation... between a quantitative variable and an ordinal variable, based on the assumption that the joint distribution of the quantitative variable and a latent continuous variable underlying the ordinal variable is bivariate normal.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/polycor/versions/0.7-9/topics/polyserial)

Comment: Also, consider Kendall correlation.

Comment: polyserial correlation works very well. this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: ***data*** are never "parametric" or "nonparametric". ***analyses*** are.